# How to make the Angry Birds "shot arch" dotted line?

Tags: physics, box2d, andengine

I am making a game that includes 2D projectile flight paths like that of Angry Birds. Angry Birds employs the notion that a previous shot is shown with a dotted line "arch" showing the player where that last shot went. I think recording that data is simple enough once a shot is fired, but in my game, I want to show it preemptively, ie: before the shot. How would I go about calculating this dotted line? The other caveat is I have wind in my game. How can you determine a projectile preemptively when wind will affect it too? This seems like a pretty tough problem. My wind right now just applies a constant force every step of animation in the direction of the wind flow. I'm using Box2D and AndEngine if it matters.

Comment: I have deleted my answer and posted under the question that this one duplicates. It's basically the same, I have update the answer to be applicable to both cases.